# Alterar configuração de "character" e "collation"

Tags: mysql, sql, configuração

Tenho uma configuração em um banco de dados da seguinte forma:

---

```
SERVIDOR 1

show variables like '%version%';

innodb_version           1.1.8
protocol_version         10
slave_type_conversions  
version                  5.5.19-log
version_comment          MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
version_compile_machine  x86_64
version_compile_os       Linux

show variables like '%character%';

character_set_client     utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database   latin1
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results    utf8
character_set_server     latin1
character_set_system     utf8
character_sets_dir       /usr/share/mysql/charsets/

show variables like 'collation%';

collation_connection     utf8_general_ci
collation_database       latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server         latin1_swedish_ci
```

---

E no outro Servidor, configuração da seguinte forma:

```
SERVIDOR 2

show variables like '%version%';

innodb_version           5.6.22
protocol_version         10
slave_type_conversions  
version                  5.6.22-log
version_comment          MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine  x86_64
version_compile_os       Win64

show variables like '%character%';

character_set_client     utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database   utf8
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results    utf8
character_set_server     utf8
character_set_system     utf8
character_sets_dir       C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\

show variables like 'collation%';

collation_connection     utf8_general_ci
collation_database       utf8_general_ci
collation_server         utf8_general_ci
```

Necessito que Servidor 2 fique idêntico ao Servidor 1.
Nota-se que a diferença de configuração está nos seguintes itens:

```
character_set_database  (alterar para "latin1")
character_set_server    (alterar para "latin1")
collation_database      (alterar para "latin1_swedish_ci")
collation_server        (alterar para "latin1_swedish_ci")
```

Tentei pelos comandos "SET", mas não surtiu efeito, mesmo por linha de comando.

É possível alterar? Como fazer?

Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Isso é bem simples, basta alterares o character e o collate da tua base de dados do servidor 2:

```
ALTER DATABASE tua_Base_de_Dados DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
```

E como diz [nesta resposta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29818/54836) adicionar estas linhas no arquivo `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
character_set_database=latin1
character_set_server=latin1
```

Comment: [mysqld]
character_set_database=latin1
character_set_server=latin1

Não funciona, ao tentar iniciar o serviço, ocorre erro.

Comment: Pois detetei o mesmo problema @mcardoso , vou tentar resolver.

Comment: Ainda não consegui...Alguma solução?

Comment: Também ainda estou a tentar resolver @mcardoso